# Does google cloud have something like "lambda@edge origin response"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cdn

Aws let setup lambda@edge function executed after a response is received from the origin(see picture bellow), can I do it with GCP?

[image: structure]

Comment: As of now, there is no Google Cloud product similar to AWS’ Lambda@Edge. However, I have opened a feature request for you. You can star the issue link [1] for follow-ups on this feature request.

[1]:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138254166

Comment: It's cool, thx for it

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE

This can be done now with the Cloud Functions service in Google Cloud Platform, as stated in the official documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/functions#all-features).

"Cloud Functions allows you to trigger your code from Google Cloud, Firebase, and Google Assistant, or call it directly from any web, mobile, or backend application via HTTP."

In this document can find the features comparison of AWS and Azure with matching features in GCP, including the one just mentioned of GCP Cloud Run matching AWS Lambda [2](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/aws-azure-gcp-service-comparison?hl=en).

Finally, can find documentation on how to write Cloud Functions, the different programming languages used, and examples for the different usages here [3](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing).

Comment: Note: Google Cloud Functions (and Cloud Run) don't run at the edge like lambda@edge functions do...you can make them multi-regional around the world, but the "edge" is even more local than that.